# Drag and drag unfunctional in programs started from Launchy in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drag-and-drop, launchy

**What is causing programs started from [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) to lose drag-and-drop functionality in Windows 10?** There were no problems like this before I installed Windows 10 (Windows 8, 7, Vista, etc), so I think the root cause is related to Windows 10.

For example:

- I used to be able to drag a file from the desktop/file explorer and drop it over Paint.net to open it.
- However, now dragging a file to Paint.net results in a "not allowed" icon.
- Drag-and-drop works as expected if Paint.net is started via other means besides Launchy. Drag-and-drop *usually* works if the program is started directly from Windows.

I have tried, without success:

- Starting Launchy with various compatibility settings.
- Starting Launchy as an Administrator

Some related issues:

- I also cannot get Launchy to automatically start with Windows on log-in like I used to. (Windows error dialogs, or it just doesn't start.)
- VLC drag-and-drop did not function irregardless of how it was started. Adjusting the "compatibility settings" restored drag-and-drop (still doesn't work if started from Launchy)
- I restored drag-and-drop to TransCopyManager in a similar fashion.

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 1):

<s>I found out that starting Launchy from task scheduler (on logon) makes the programs started from loose drag-drop functionality.</s> If I run it manually then it works fine. To start Launchy from startup:

1. press Win+R
2. type shell::startup and press enter - this will open startup directory
3. drag Launchy executable with **right** button to startup directory and choose create shortcut
4. alternatively copy the executable, right click in startup and choose paste shortcut.

P.S. [Wox](https://github.com/Wox-launcher/Wox/releases) url is changed to http://www.wox.one/

**Update:** The drag and drop doesn't depend on Launchy. It depends on weather or not the program you are dragging from has the same privileges as the program you are dropping to. For example if you start Launchy with as administrator (for example in task scheduler and you tick the box "Run with higher privileges") it will start all programs as administrator. And the reason you want to start Launchy as administrator is that hotkey won't work if the focused window is a program run as administrator.

I'm using AutoHotkey which is started as administrator to convert Win+Space to Alt-Ctrl-Space since Win+space doesn't work in Launchy, Wox or keypirinha. That fixes the hotkey not working in programs started with higher privileges. I start launchy itself **not** as administrator.

Comment: Thanks~ I use https://keypirinha.com/ now.

Comment: I wrote it in case someone else needs it. Btw wox doesn't even come close to launchy. typing the same letters won't give you the same program. you have to continue typing or select  manually every time. I'll try keypirinha - thanks for sharing. (I can see keypirinha fixed the wox problem)

Comment: keypirinha has few problems: since windows 7 both keypirinha and launchy cannot use win+space as hotkey, so I use autohotkey to convert win+space to alt-ctrl-space. keypirinha doesn't work with autohotkey - it opens and closes immediately. Also not having settings window doesn't help much , but it's not a show stopper. The show stopper is that I used Win+Space since windows XP and I can't find any other useful hotkey - I use everything else in other programs

Comment: I just use alt-space; never realized win-space doesn't work. However if you really want win-space, Windows Power Toys Key Remapper works: https://superuser.com/a/1556350/4390

Answer (score 0):

I found a replacement for Launchy that does not have this problem: [Wox](http://www.getwox.com/)

The interface is very similar, and it is in active development.